# DATEPART as a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm guessing this is not possible since the engine doesn't like it, but is there a way (barring dynamic SQL) to pass in a `DATEPART` as a parameter to a procedure?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to use a CASE with the parameter (it would be better to use an int enumeration instead of string):

```
declare @part varchar(10)
set @part = 'YEAR'
select case @part 
            when 'YEAR' then datepart(yy, SomeDateTimeColumn) 
            when 'MONTH' then datepart(mm, SomeDateTimeColumn) 
            else datepart(dd, SomeDateTimeColumn) 
        end
from SomeTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just pass in the Date that is created from the Datepart?

```
DECLARE @datepart DATETIME
SET @datepart = DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())

exec spName @datepart
```

Comment: very good idea and I think you'll be my answer; however, I wanted to pass in 'YEAR' or 'MONTH', not some *seemingly* arbitrary date.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no "year" datatype. You can do this:

```
CREATE PROC myproc @Year int, @Month tinyint
```

This fails because DATEPART part is a literal

```
DECLARE @part varchar(10)
SET @part = 'month'
SELECT DATEPART(@part, GETDATE());
```

or this and an IF ELSE

```
CREATE PROC myproc @WhoeDate datetime, @part varchar(10) /* year. month etc*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to always add months (or even days if you need it on that level) and to play with integer values. Something like this

```
DECLARE @AddMonths INT = 12
SELECT 
  Sales_DateTime, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, @AddMonths, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Sales_DateTime ))) 
FROM tSales
```

and I think it's clear how to add one month only :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a dynamic stored procedure the following code could you help you to achieve this.

When you define the body of the sp, remember that you need to use exec sql key-word to execute the sql sentence:

```
create proc sp_dinamic_procedure(@datepart_sql varchar(20), @datepart_var varchar(8) )
as
begin   
    declare @query varchar(100) 
    select @query = "select date from table1 t1 where datepart(" + @datepart_var + ", t1.fecha1) = " + @datepart_sql
    exec @query
end
```

Then you can pass any sql sentence to your stored procedure as a single string dependig on your needs:

```
declare @datepart_sql varchar(20), @datepart_var varchar(8)
select @datepart_sql = "datepart(year,getdate()", @datepart_var = "year"
exec sp_dinamic_procedure @datepart_sql, @datepart_var
```